# AngularJS - sections with common functionality

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, module, ng-controller

I am creating an AngularJS app which has different sections. In one section the sub-sections have the exact same functionality, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this without writing the same code for every section.

Here is the navigation structure:

```
Campaign(section)
    - notifications(sub-section)
        - active
        - inactive
        - draft
        - sent
    - messages(sub-section)
        - active
        - paused
        - draft
        - scheduled
    - conversation(sub-section)
        - active
        - paused
        - draft
        - scheduled
```

All the sub-sections have the same functionality, for example showing active messages when a "notifications" button is clicked. Another example is when an "inactive" button is clicked, and so on.

The message template may be different for each sub section link (like active, inactive). I want to know how i can achieve this without writing multiple controllers and views.

Answer (score 1):

To me it's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve but it sounds like you need to write a couple of directives.  This is a pseudo-example of how you can write a main directive with an accessible controller that gets passed to sub-directives.  This mirrors the same relationship that a series of controllers have with a common service.

## pseudo code

```
directive('outerDirective', [
  function() {
    return {
      controllerAs: 'outerDirectiveVc',
      controller: [/* injectables & your controller function */]
    }
  }
])
.directive('innerDirective', [
  function() {
    return {
      require: '^outerDirective',
      link: function($scope, elem, attrs, outerDirectiveVc) {
        outerDirectiveVc.someFunc()
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The nice thing about using the directive approach is that you can use them for just the reusable portion of the UI via the templates (if applicable).

The *inner directive's* `require: '^outerDirective'` will a) ensure that you have an *outer directive* declared somewhere in the DOM hierarchy above it and b) allows you to access the controller via the `outerDirectiveVc` parameter in its *link* function.

Without knowing more about your use case I can't really tailor this answer to your specific UX but I hope this gets you started in thinking about directives.